# KODI configuration for PPT,PPS files

Tags: xml, server, powerpoint, kodi

I have been working with kodi these days. I have two servers, Server1 is for data files e.g. Videos, PPT/PPS files. And Server 2 is where KODI is installed.

NOW I have done below update in KODI XMLs for configuring KODI for opening PPT files using libra office.

playercorefactory.xml-

```
<playercorefactory>                                           
  <players>                                                   
    <player name="libreoffice" type="ExternalPlayer">         
     <filename>bash</filename>                                
     <args>/etc/bash_completion.d/libreoffice.sh "{1}"</args>               
     <hidexbmc>false</hidexbmc>                               
     <hideconsole>false</hideconsole>                         
     <warpcursor>none</warpcursor>                            
    </player>                                                 
  </players>                                                  

  <rules action="prepend">                                    
    <rule name="ppt" filetypes="ppt" player="libreoffice" />  
    <rule name="pptx" filetypes="pptx" player="libreoffice" />
    <rule name="pdf" filetypes="pdf" player="libreoffice" />  
  </rules>                                                    
</playercorefactory>
```

Sources.xml

```
<sources>
    <programs>
        <default pathversion="1"></default>
    </programs>
    <video>
        <default pathversion="1"></default>
        <source>
            <name>videos</name>
            <path pathversion="1">smb://192.168.1.162/<projectfolder>/videos/</path>
            <allowsharing>true</allowsharing>
        </source>
    </video>
    <music>
        <default pathversion="1"></default>
        <source>
            <name>Music</name>
            <path pathversion="1">smb://192.168.1.162/home/tft/<projectfolder>/music/</path>
            <allowsharing>true</allowsharing>
        </source>
        <source>
            <name>Music Playlists</name>
            <path pathversion="1">special://musicplaylists/</path>
            <allowsharing>true</allowsharing>
        </source>
    </music>
    <pictures>
        <default pathversion="1"></default>
        <source>
            <name>pictures</name>
            <path pathversion="1">smb://192.168.1.162/<projectfolder>/pictures/</path>
            <allowsharing>true</allowsharing>
        </source>
    </pictures>
    <files>
        <default pathversion="1"></default>
    </files>
    <games>
        <default pathversion="1"></default>
    </games>
</sources>
```

advancedsettings.xml

```
    <advancedsettings>
      <videodatabase>
        <type>mysql</type>
        <host>192.168.1.162</host>
        <port>3306</port>
        <user>root</user>
        <pass>root</pass>
      </videodatabase>
      <musicdatabase>
        <type>mysql</type>
        <host>192.168.1.162</host>
        <port>3306</port>
        <user>root</user>
        <pass>root</pass>
      </musicdatabase>
      <videolibrary>
        <importwatchedstate>true</importwatchedstate>
        <importresumepoint>true</importresumepoint>
      </videolibrary>
      <loglevel>2</loglevel> <!-- Change this to "1" to hide the on-screen debug log text -->
        <debug>
            <extralogging>true</extralogging>
            <setextraloglevel>32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192,16384,32768,65536</setextraloglevel>
            <showloginfo>true</showloginfo>
        </debug>

  <pictureextensions>
    <add>.ppt</add>
  </pictureextensions>

    </advancedsettings>
```

Now issues is:
KODI is recognising the PPT files and its being showed in the KODI but when i tried to click and play, black screen appears. Seems like kodi is not picking up the Libraoffice to run the PPT file. How can i resolve this?

Im really seeking the resolution. Im stucked with this issue since more than 15 days now.